# Code returns a strongly types RCW and system.__ComObject and fails with InvalidCastException

Tags: .net, vb.net, com, vb6, interop

I have some .net code and older VB6 code that needs to interact and pass objects between the two.  I have found that under slightly different coding conditions I get different results and this makes the code un-reliable.

The problem occurs when .net creates a com object, and it depends on how this object is created (or how .NET first accesses the object?).  The com objects are defined in VB6 and have 2 interfaces.  This causes me issues when I need to get access to the underlying interface the code fails with InvalidCastException

Some examples are below.

This code is written in .net

In VB6 we have an object called Inter1 and Inter2.  Inter2 implements Inter1

```
'The following is a com object 
Dim ComObj as New Inter2
'In debug mode hovering over ComObj will display ComObjClass
Dim ComObj2 as Inter1 = Inter2
'This code you would expect to work - but fails with InvalidCastException
```

If the above code is re-written like this then it will work

```
'The following is a com object 
Dim ComObj as Inter2 = CreateObject("Inter2")
'In debug mode hovering over ComObj will display System.__ComObject
Dim ComObj2 as Inter1 = Inter2
'This code will now work as expected and Inter1 can be accessed.
```

I believe that the issue somehow relates to how the RCW is created.  The issue also occurs in code similiar to below where I already have a COM object and a property on this object will return another com object as follows

```
'here we already have a com object called ComApp
Dim ComObj as Inter2 = ComApp.GetInter2
'In debug mode hovering over ComObj will display ComObjClass
Dim ComObj2 as Inter1 = Inter2
'This code you would expect to work - but fails with InvalidCastException
```

In the application I am working in the above is more common, and I have no easy solution as the object is created by the COM applciation and returned to the .net applicaiton.

I am hoping here is a way to force .NET to always return RCW as System.__ComObject rather then what appears to be strongly-typed com wrapper that does not appear to correctly support inheritance?

The code I have provided isa very breif summary, but hopefully enough to demonstrate the issue.

Thanks for your help

Comment: VB6 was too long ago, but iirc VB6 can only support classes with a single interface when you early-bind.  A workaround is to add a property that returns the other interface.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem and it relates to how you link it to the associated dll.  The key settings are as follows.

With the linked in com dll - if you select the option for "Embed Interop Types" = false then the behaviour described above occurs.

If you select True they will always return as system.__ComObject, and this solves the problem.

Was not hard to fix, but very difficult to locate the problem.

Hope this helps someone else out there?